# Is it okay to write "non-resident" for non-resident alien spouse's SSN?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, itin

I live outside the US with my non-resident alien spouse. I want to file as married filing separately. However, in online tax preparation software, it always forces me to enter an ITIN or SSN for my spouse, even if she is a non-resident alien. Is this really required? I saw an [article on HR Block](https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/filing/personal-tax-planning/tax-help-for-us-citizen-married-to-non-resident/) that says "The nonresident spouse isn’t required to get a taxpayer ID number. You can put “NR” for your spouse’s tax ID number on your return." That would be very convenient as I wouldn't need to apply for her to get an ITIN. However, on [this IRS website page](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-alien-spouse), there is a line that says, "If your spouse is a nonresident alien and you file a joint ***or separate*** return, your spouse must have either a Social Security Number (SSN) or an Individual Taxpayer Identification Number (ITIN)". Nonetheless it seems a little strange that a non-resident alien spouse with no US income would need to apply for an ITIN just because she is the wife of a US citizen. Even if I file separately, do I still need to enter an ITIN for my spouse? Or can I just write "NR"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Form 1040 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf), section for filing status Married Filing Separately (on page 13), it says:

> Check  the  “Married  filing  separately” box at the top of Form 1040
>   or 1040-SR if you are married and file a separate return.  Enter 
>   your  spouse’s  name  in  the entry  space  below  the  filing  status
>   checkboxes. Be sure to enter your spouse’s SSN or ITIN in the space
>   for spouse’s SSN on Form 1040 or 1040-SR. **If your  spouse  doesn’t 
>   have  and  isn’t  required  to  have  an  SSN  or  ITIN,  enter
>   “NRA.”**

(emphasis mine)

So yes, it seems you can write "NRA" in the space for your spouse's SSN/ITIN in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much. Wow, so I guess IRA also makes mistakes on their website.

Comment: I think the quote you consider a "mistake" is only relevant for resident aliens; your wife is not a resident alien, as neither of you reside in the US.