# Free E-file US taxes if spouse is non-resident alien

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, itin, free-file-fillable-forms

I have a special situation in that I am a US citizen but my spouse is a non-resident alien, and I myself also live overseas. So far I have only found that HR Block Taxes for Expats lets me e-file married filing separately when my spouse has no ITIN/SSN. Turbo tax made me enter an ITIN/SSN to e-file. I was wondering if there is anyone knows of a free e-file software that doesn't require an NRA spouse to enter their ITIN/SSN?

Thanks in advance,

Philip

Comment: I'd be interested to see if the IRS' own Free File Fillable allows it. But you'd have to set up an account with IRS to see: https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/free-file-fillable-forms

Comment: Thanks, my taxes are relatively simple so this year I just printed out the various documents (referencing my last year's taxes handled by HR Block's software) and filled it out by hand and mailed it in

Answer (score -1):

> **Social Security Number**
>
> If **your spouse** is a nonresident alien and you file a joint or **separate
> return**, **your spouse** must have either a Social Security Number (SSN) or
> an Individual Taxpayer Identification Number (ITIN). To get an SSN for
> **your spouse**, apply at a social security office or U.S. consulate. You
> must complete **Form SS-5**. You must also provide original or certified
> copies of documents to verify your spouse's age, identity, and
> citizenship. If your spouse is not eligible to get an SSN, he or she
> can file **Form W-7** with the IRS to apply for an ITIN. Refer to
> [Taxpayer Identification Numbers (TIN)](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayer-identification-numbers-tin) for more information.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-alien-spouse

Comment: Thanks. This seems to contradict what is said in https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/119406/is-it-okay-to-write-non-resident-for-non-resident-alien-spouses-ssn?rq=1
I guess IRS is also fallible
I believe it should still be okay to write NRA though instead of an ITIN

Comment: @Philip: Although the TY2020 1040 instructions (issued in Jan and revised in Feb, both more recent than that webpage) continue to say the same as #119406 said for 2019, that is you can write in NRA -- at least on paper; whether a _FreeFile_ app supports this could be a different question, as they aren't required to support all possible filers below the threshold. Of course if you do file W7 you must attach it to a paper return, you can't efile at all (free or paid).